# android:fullBackupOnly in AndroidManifest.xml, for what?

Tags: android

While I coding, I found this option `android:fullBackupOnly` (I set it to **"true"**), it is for backup all the app's data, include cache files and so on?!

- Hint: Also, I using `android:allowBackup="true"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This official reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fullBackupOnly) says,

> Indicates that even though the application provides a
>   `BackupAgent`, only full-data streaming backup operations are to be
>   performed to save the app's data. This lets the app rely on full-data
>   backups while still participating in the backup and restore process
>   via the `BackupAgent`'s full-data backup APIs. When this attribute is
>   true the app's BackupAgent overrides of the `onBackup()` and
>   `onRestore()` callbacks can be empty stubs.

Answer (score 20):

Android versions before Marshmallow had a backup system that required a significant developer effort to implement. If you implemented that system, but you want your app to use the new backup system on devices where it's available, you can set this flag to disable the old backup system only on devices where the new system is available. This is better than removing your implementation of the old backup system, because older devices will continue to back up with the old system. If you didn't implement the old backup system, or will remove it from your app, you don't need this flag.

Here's a reference: http://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html#previous-androids

Comment: IMO this should be the accepted answer. Defines the distinction much clearer.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, i understood what it is.. otherwise the official documentation doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it won't automatically back up cache files -- the base implementation understands that these are unlikely to be suitable for backup/restore, and ignores them.